# Recover the deleted files in ubuntu + amazon ec2

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2

How I would recover the recent deleted files from amazon ec2 ubuntu server.For example The all "tar" files are removed unfortunately in amazon ec2 + ubuntu 11.04 instance.

The removed files should be retrieved.

How it is supposed to do?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [extundelete](http://extundelete.sourceforge.net/) to recover your files if your file system is ext3 or ext4.

Comment: i tried extundelete - it tells me to unmount the device

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [Photorec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) - it has had success recovering data from EBS volumes before (although, since EBS is a 'block' device, any undelete tool should work). It is more of a 'guided' process as opposed to a single command (more GUI like, if you will). It looks for known file headers to match against deleted files - the list of supported file types can be found [here](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/File_Formats_Recovered_By_PhotoRec). (I believe the package name is `[testdisk][3]`)

The Ubuntu page on [data recovery](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery) may also be a worthwhile read.